# Writing custom java serializers for classes not in the same path

Tags: java, serialization

So I would like to write custom serializers for some classes I have.  I need two formats, one a human readable and editable yaml format, and one just for internal use that can be binary.  I know about Externalizable but since I have two formats I'm not sure this is appropriate.

Ideally I would like to have the custom serializers as separate classes in a separate packages. This is because if I write a generic serializer, I want to use it for all classes, not just the ones inside of a particular package. I also would like to stay away from JavaBeans as I won't always have code access to the classes I want to serialize.

But this is where I get stuck, I want access to the private variables inside of the classes, and I know I can "disable" the private using reflection, but won't that prevent me from running this on many java systems due to security?

How should I go about writing my generic serializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your own custom serializable. For binary encoding use Java's serialization. And for encoding it into a human readable format you can convert your class into a JSON/XML format. Google `Gson` library can be used to convert a Java class into JSON and vice-versa.

So to write your generic serialization use combination of Java's inbuilt serialization API and your own technique to convert object into human readable format.

**Update**

You can use Reflection technique to create your own custom human readable format of object. For details on Reflection you can read my [blog](http://geekrai.blogspot.in/2013/02/reflecting-on-java-reflection.html).

Comment: Those are pretty big libraries, I was looking more of how they actually are able to access the members?  Also unfortunately I need to do yaml, which I don't think is inside Googles library

Comment: they use reflection. You can write your own reflection utility.

Comment: You should put that in your answer, but that brings up my other question I asked, won't that prevent me from running on many java systems? Do you know anything about the prevalence of people that have those reflection abilities turned off?

Comment: Reflection can't be turned off. I have updated my post as well.

Comment: I was more talking about the direct access to the private members, which need field.setAccessible(true);  Do you know anything about whether its common practice to remove that?  if you do I'll go ahead and mark yours as the answer

Comment: Yeah, by default you can not access private members of the class through Reflection. But as you said you can access it by enabling access through setAssible(true) method. This is not a general practice but if you want to access private members then its perfectly alright.